# how to connect a dropdown menu with a text input with html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using Sublime and I want to connect a dropdown menu with an input text with html, css and javascript. So the user clicking on the dropdown menu must visualize in the text input the result. In this case if the user clicks on "italian" in the text input must see "italian"

I have written the code but it doesn't works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <style>
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>
</head>
<title>Calculators</title>
<body bgcolor="yellow">
    <h1 style="color:red;">Calculators:</h1><br>

    <p style="margin-left: 50px;">
    <a href="C:\Users\ALBINO\Desktop\prove\calculator\index.html" target="_self">Example Calculator</a><br>
    <a href="index2.html" target="_self">Italian Calculators</a><br>
    <a href="http://web2.0calc.com/">Online Scientific Calculator</a>
    </p>
    <!--<script src="logic.js"></script> http://www.qatarstationery.com/image/cache/data/Calculator%20MJ100%20-%20Casio-900x900.jpeg-->

    <div id="examplePicture" style="margin-left: 500px;">
        <img src="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/$T2eC16NHJIkE9qU3jckhBRY0k-ob)!~~_35.JPG" />
    </div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction() class="dropbtn" >Choose your favourite calculator</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">italian</a>
    <a href="#">german</a>
    <a href="#">brazilian</a>
    <a href="#">french</a>
    <a href="#">spaniard</a>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="text" id="display" disabled><br>

<script src="homeJava.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my javascript code:

```
var box = document.getElementById('display');

function myFunction() {
    box.value += document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.();
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: may be you added an extra dot in the classList method. try doing this

`var box = document.getElementById('display');

function myFunction() {
    box.value += document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList();
}`

Comment: @abdul ahad may you give me an example?

Comment: Did any of these answers help you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add this function on change in your html code

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn" >Choose your favourite calculator</button>
<div id="myDropdown" onchange="myFunction()" class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">italian</a>
  <a href="#">german</a>
  <a href="#">brazilian</a>
  <a href="#">french</a>
  <a href="#">spaniard</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

And in your js file:

```
function myFunction{

 $("#myDropdown option:selected").each(function () {
        getSelectedItem = $(this).val();
        $("#display").val(getSelectedItem);
 });
}
```

Comment: won't work, because the content of the selected `a` tag is not considered the .val() of the parent div

Comment: so he want to change `a` tag `option` tag all this option into a `select`  tag. and he should using jQuery to that for this solution works

Answer (score 0):

well this can be a workaround

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <style>
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>
</head>
<title>Calculators</title>
<body bgcolor="yellow">
    <h1 style="color:red;">Calculators:</h1><br>

    <p style="margin-left: 50px;">
    <a href="C:\Users\ALBINO\Desktop\prove\calculator\index.html" target="_self">Example Calculator</a><br>
    <a href="index2.html" target="_self">Italian Calculators</a><br>
    <a href="http://web2.0calc.com/">Online Scientific Calculator</a>
    </p>
    <!--<script src="logic.js"></script> http://www.qatarstationery.com/image/cache/data/Calculator%20MJ100%20-%20Casio-900x900.jpeg-->

    <div id="examplePicture" style="margin-left: 500px;">
        <img src="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/$T2eC16NHJIkE9qU3jckhBRY0k-ob)!~~_35.JPG" />
    </div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" >Choose your favourite calculator</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a onclick="myFunction('italian')">italian</a>
    <a onclick="myFunction('german')">german</a>
    <a onclick="myFunction('brazilian')">brazilian</a>
    <a onclick="myFunction('french')">french</a>
    <a onclick="myFunction('spaniard')">spaniard</a>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="text" id="display" disabled><br>

<script>
    var box = document.getElementById('display');

    function myFunction(text) {
        box.value = text;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a click listener on your `<a>` elements, children of *#myDropdown*

```js
var a = document.getElementById('myDropdown').querySelectorAll('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      // Set listener
      a[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        // On click, set the input value with the <a> content
        document.getElementById('display').value = this.innerHTML;
      });
    }
```

```html
<div id="myDropdown" onchange="myFunction()" class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">italian</a>
  <a href="#">german</a>
  <a href="#">brazilian</a>
  <a href="#">french</a>
  <a href="#">spaniard</a>
 </div>

<input type="text" id="display" disabled><br>
```